# `fetch` call during nextjs app into my own api returns error: "unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled"

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have an api in my nextjs app with this code:

```js
import https from 'https';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const response = await fetch('https://my.api.com/api/',
        {
            agent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
            })
        });
    const data = await response.json()
    return new Response('foo');
}
```

And get back the following error when running that:

> error - FetchError: request to https://my.api.com/api/ failed, reason: write EPROTO 88850000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:

```
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\projects\foo-health\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'EPROTO',
code: 'EPROTO'
}
```

I'm running the following versions:

- next 13.3.1
- Node.js v20.0.0